# mulesoft dataweave - don't see list output with mapObject

Tags: listview, dataweave, mulesoft

Don't see list output

1. Input XML has a list
2. Expected output
3. DataWeave code
4. What output did I get

Input xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<expandedNoteList>
  <expandedNote>
    <noteType>Discharge</noteType>
    <noteText>test discharge 2</noteText>
    <createdID>gpdSdoCaSupervisor</createdID>
    <createdName>SDO CA Supervisor</createdName>
    <createTimeStamp>2019-09-11T14:14:00.000-05:00</createTimeStamp>
  </expandedNote>
  <expandedNote>
    <noteType>Discharge</noteType>
    <noteText>test discharge notes</noteText>
    <createdID>gpdSdoCaSupervisor</createdID>
    <createdName>SDO CA Supervisor</createdName>
    <createTimeStamp>2019-09-11T14:01:00.000-05:00</createTimeStamp>
  </expandedNote>
</expandedNoteList>
```

DataWeave scrpit:

```
extendedNote: [ 
      (payload.expandedNoteList mapObject { 
           "expandedNoteDateTime": $.createTimeStamp,    
           "expandedNoteType": $.noteType,
           "expandedNoteText": $.noteText,
      }
     ) if(payload.expandedNoteList !=null),
 ],
```

Comment: - json expected output:

{
  "extendedNote": [
  {
    "expandedNoteDateTime": "2019-09-11T14:14:00Z",
    "expandedNoteType": "Discharge",
    "expandedNoteText": "test discharge 2"
  },
  {
    "expandedNoteDateTime": "2019-09-11T14:01:00Z",
    "expandedNoteType": "Discharge",
    "expandedNoteText": "test discharge notes"
  }
 ],
}

Comment: - Returned output by above DataWeave script:


{
  "extendedNote": [
  {
     "expandedNoteDateTime": "2019-09-11T14:14:00.000-05:00",
     "expandedNoteType": "Discharge",
     "expandedNoteText": "test discharge 2",
     "expandedNoteDateTime": "2019-09-11T14:01:00.000-05:00",
     "expandedNoteType": "Discharge",
     "expandedNoteText": "test discharge notes"
  }
 ],
}

Comment: this worked -
extendedNote: [ 
 
(payload.expandedNoteList mapObject 
 a: { 
   "expandedNoteDateTime": $.createTimeStamp,
  "expandedNoteType": $.noteType,
  "expandedNoteText": $.noteText,
 }
 ) if(payload.expandedNoteList !=null),
 
].*a

Comment: Please read [ask] then [edit] your question. Don't use comments to clarify; code is unreadable in comments.

Answer (score 1):

The following Dataweave code should work:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
extendedNote: payload..*expandedNote map
{
      "expandedNoteDateTime": $.createTimeStamp,
      "expandedNoteType": $.noteType,
      "expandedNoteText": $.noteText
}
```

output:

```
{
  "extendedNote": [
    {
      "expandedNoteDateTime": "2019-09-11T14:14:00.000-05:00",
      "expandedNoteType": "Discharge",
      "expandedNoteText": "test discharge 2"
    },
    {
      "expandedNoteDateTime": "2019-09-11T14:01:00.000-05:00",
      "expandedNoteType": "Discharge",
      "expandedNoteText": "test discharge notes"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: this worked -
extendedNote: [ 
 
(payload.expandedNoteList mapObject 
 a: { 
   "expandedNoteDateTime": $.createTimeStamp,
  "expandedNoteType": $.noteType,
  "expandedNoteText": $.noteText,
 }
 ) if(payload.expandedNoteList !=null),
 
].*a